# How to make right request with curl

Tags: curl, url-encoding, busybox

Problem as follows:
I have a shorter version of a bash. My shell environment is a busybox.
And there is a site `api.kinobaza.ru` I refer to him with the following bash code:

```
url="api.kinobaza.tv/films/lookup/?"
film="names[1]=Терминатор"
curl -s $url --data-urlencode $film
```

Response from the server only empty brackets `[]`
But when I write a reference `api.kinobaza.tv/films/lookup/?names[1]=Терминатор` in the browser returns multiline response required, such as the need.

How I can get the same result in bash with curl as in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you encode the square brackets as well, thus changing the query part of the url.

Comment: Well, actually I cannot reproduce the problem. If I execute your script it works fine for me. I get quite some details about that film. I use bash, though.

Comment: Well, very strange, I just performed this script again - the result of empty parentheses. In what may be the problem? in the computer?

Comment: Try to replace the last line (the curl call) by this: `echo "curl -s $url --data-urlencode $film"` and post the result. Let's compare!

Comment: )))) Ok
`curl -s api.kinobaza.tv/films/lookup/? --data-urlencode names[1]=Терминатор`

Comment: Hm, what does this produce: `wget http://api.kinobaza.tv/films/lookup/?names[1]=Терминатор` ?

Comment: `Connecting to api.kinobaza.tv (95.169.190.115:80)
?names[1]=Терминатор 100% |******************************************************|     2  --:--:-- ETA`

Comment: It should have saved some file (something called "index..."). What's inside?

Comment: `cat ?names\[1\]\=Терминатор`
Result is `[]`

Comment: There is something wrong in this... PLease try this instead: `wget -O - http://api.kinobaza.tv/films/lookup/?names[1]=Терминатор`

Comment: `Connecting to api.kinobaza.tv (95.169.190.115:80)
-                      0% |                                                      |     0  --:--:-- ETA[-                    100% |******************************************************|     2  --:--:-- ETA
`

Comment: Something is strange with you shell environment, how it treats commands. If you are using busybox than that might be the problem. I am afraid I cannot help with that, since I have a full environment here. Sorry.